# connecting to xrdp from Remmina via VPN

Tags: vpn, xrdp, remmina

My University computer is running on Ubuntu 22.04 and have xrdp installed. My home computer is Dell-Inspiron with Ubuntu 20.04. The connection to the University is via VPN Pulse-Secure. The  VPN connection is to my University SSL server. When the VPN connection is established, I try to connect to the xrdp server on my University computer using Remmina RDP protocol. The connection fails. This is the output of the Remmina:

```
me@me-Inspiron:/$ remmina
Remmina plugin glibsecret (type=Secret) has registered but not yet initialized/activated. Initialization order is 2000.
Secret plugin glibsecret has been successfully initialized and will be your default secret plugin
StatusNotifier/Appindicator support: your desktop does support it and libappindicator is compiled in remmina. Good!
Running under Gnome Shell version 3.36.9
(org.remmina.Remmina:78170): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:25:20.996: gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(): menu already attached to GtkMenuItem
[09:25:27:583] [78170:78177] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_connect:freerdp_set_last_error_ex resetting error state
[09:25:27:583] [78170:78177] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpdr
[09:25:27:583] [78170:78177] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpsnd
[09:25:27:583] [78170:78177] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr
[09:25:27:583] [78170:78177] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx drdynvc
[09:25:27:901] [78170:78177] [INFO][com.freerdp.primitives] - primitives autodetect, using optimized
[09:25:27:902] [78170:78177] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_tcp_is_hostname_resolvable:freerdp_set_last_error_ex resetting error state
[09:25:27:902] [78170:78177] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_tcp_connect:freerdp_set_last_error_ex resetting error state
[09:25:42:917] [78170:78177] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_tcp_connect:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_FAILED [0x00020006]
[09:25:42:917] [78170:78177] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - failed to connect to 137.74.123.144
```

Using the same VPN from Windows connects to the xrdp server with no problem. How to I diagnose and fix this issue? Will other remote controls like VNC may work better over VPN?
Thank you
Following @Saxtheowl suggestions I tried to ping internal IP and got this output:

> me@me-Inspiron:/$ ping 10.100.102.80 PING 10.100.102.80
> (10.100.102.80) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 10.100.102.80:
> icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms 64 bytes from 10.100.102.80:
> icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
>
> ^C
> --- 10.100.102.80 ping statistics --- 9 packets transmitted, 9 received, 0% packet loss, time 8185ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
> 0.037/0.074/0.141/0.029 ms
>
> me@me-Inspiron:/$ ping 127.0.0.1 PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84)
> bytes of data. 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.047
> ms 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms ^C
> --- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics --- 7 packets transmitted, 7 > received, 0% packet loss, time 6123ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
> 0.047/0.062/0.076/0.008 ms

running

```
xfreerdp /u:remote /v:142.75.133.134:3389
```

and

```
sudo ufw disable
```

did not help.

Comment: The Remmina output says faired to connect to ` 137.74.123.144` while you are pinging `10.100.102.80`. Try connecting to `10.100.102.80` using Remmina.

Answer (score 0):

There is some stuff you can do to diagnose your problem, try to ping internal ip addresses, check again your xdrp ip addresses and port, temporary disable ufw with `sudo ufw disable`, you also try another RDP client like `FreeRDP` s

```
sudo apt install freerdp2-x11
xfreerdp /u:<username> /v:<server_ip_address>:<port_number>
```

Comment: Where do i ping and disable ufw? in the client?

Comment: yes in the client

Comment: It is not clear to me whether I write the actual IP address of the xrdp server such as 137.74.123.144 in the  <server_ip_address> or internal address. If it is an internal address, which one is it?

Comment: you should try with the internal

Comment: Please specify which exact IP should I use. Thank you

Comment: It would be something like 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x. with 3389 port so xfreerdp /u:<username> /v:192.168.1.100:3389